# How can I store an API auth token using React?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to store an auth token from my API, so then i can use it to make a GET request to another API, my code is the following:

```
fetch('APIURL', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: currentUser.username,
            password: currentUser.password,
        }),
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .then(json => console.log(json))
```

The username and password come from my form inputs, i have succesfully made the POST request and got the token in my browser, but I want to store it in my code, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I made it work using axios with the following code:

```
axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "APIURL",
        data: {
            username: currentUser.username,
            password: currentUser.password
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            const responseStatus = (response.status)
            const authToken = (response.data)

        })
```

Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to set & get auth token.

To save a string in Local storage you can use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

You can get the value later with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```